# Meaning of processors in elasticsearch _cluster/stats

Tags: elasticsearch

I am viewing my cluster stats in an `Elasticsearch` deployment by executing the

```
GET _cluster/stats
```

command on `kibana`'s web console.

Regarding `os.processors` info, I see this

```
    "os" : {
      "available_processors" : 6,
      "allocated_processors" : 6,
```

Given that I have a 3-node cluster, does the above imply that I have 6/3=2 processors on each node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`_cluster/stats` documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-stats.html) (emphasis added):

> - available_processors
>   (integer) Number of processors available to JVM **across all selected nodes**.
> - allocated_processors
>   (integer) Number of processors used to calculate thread pool size across all selected nodes.
>   This number can be set with the processors setting of a node and defaults to the number of processors reported by the OS. In both cases, this number will never be larger than 32.

So, to answer your question, it means you have 6 processors in total, but it could be that one node has 4 and two other nodes have only 1.

In order to know how many processor each node has, you need to hit the [`_nodes/stats` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-info.html#cluster-nodes-info-api-response-body) instead, which will contain the same fields, but relative to each node.